# jQuery: Assign clickable event to multiple divs with similar id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a site that displays multiple entries.  Each entry can be expanded/collapsed, showing more/less information.  The HTML for each entry looks like:

```
<div id="entry-1"><div>some text</div><div><img></div></div>
<div id="entry-2"><div>some text</div><div><img></div></div>
<div id="entry-3"><div>some text</div><div><img></div></div>
```

The 1,2,3 in "entry-{1,2,3}" is the id of each post.  How do I tie a click event to each div?

I tried doing:

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click( myFunc($(this)) ) ;
```

But when I click, nothing happens, the click doesn't fire even though when the page loads, the JavaScript is executed.

Comment: I recommend you use classes instead of that id's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `this` keyword. In this code...

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click( myFunc($(this)) );
```

... the `this` value doesn't point to the DOM element that has been clicked, but instead to the global object (window).

This would work:

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click(function() {
     myFunc($(this));
});
```

---

As @JCOC pointed out, you are calling the function.
In your original code, `myFunc($(this))` will be called immediately and its return value is passed into the `click()` method.

So, if your function returned `undefined`, for instance, then the resulting code would be this:

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click(undefined);
```

... which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I picked this answer because of the explanation of how the code is executed. Good to know how the events are registered when it comes to passing arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Try turning your

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click( myFunc($(this)) ) ;
```

into

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click( function(){ myFunc($(this)); } ) ;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem I see here is that you are executing the function. You could do this:

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click( myFunc ) ;

function myFunc(){
   var some = $(this);
   ...
}
```

Additionally, I previously recommended you to use classes:

```
<div id="entry-1" class="entry"></div>
<div id="entry-2" class="entry"></div>
//JS Selector:
$("div.entry")
```

So in sum:

```
$('div.entry').click( myFunc );
```

Comment: +1 you beat me. :o) Better to have `myFunc` wrap it if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what myFunc() is doing, but your selector is fine. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sYWwK/

It's logging out the div you click on:

```
$('div[id^="entry-"]').click( function() {
        console.log( $(this) );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're attaching a click listener to every single entry. A better way to accomplish this might be to attach a click listener to the parent of the entries. So, if we have the following HTML:

```
<div id="entries">
  <div id="entry-1"><div>some text</div><div><img></div></div>
  <div id="entry-2"><div>some text</div><div><img></div></div>
  <div id="entry-3"><div>some text</div><div><img></div></div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript would look something like this:

```
$('#entries').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target.id.match('entry')) {
    var entry = $(e.target);
    // logic for show more/less
  }
});
```

If you went the route that other people have suggested and used classes on each entry, the JavaScript would look more like this:

```
$('#entries').click(function (e) {  
  if (e.target.className.match('entry') || $(e.target).parents('.entry').length) {
    var entry = $(e.target);
    // logic for show more/less
  }
});
```

Comment: You're right. You'd have to check to see if a parent matched the id or class as well. I still think event delegation is a better approach to the problem.

Comment: While event delegation is great, would be easier to do something like this with jQuery's live() or delegate() methods. 

$('div[id^="entry-"]').live('click', function() { });